# Is it possible to merge add an audio file to video file with their dataURLs?

Tags: javascript, html, data-uri

I want to merge an audio file with a silent video file.
 And I only have their dataURLs.
Is it possible to merge these files with editing their dataURLs?
I'm using JS on a static webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Search for a multimedia container format that supports both file types, and hope you find one that is easy to construct from dataURLs.  It will require a header and probably other metadata about the audio and video tracks.